# Confused about the scope of object when return it from a method

Tags: c++

I create an vector object in a method, when I return the vector, it should be out of scope, but why the invoker method could still get the returned object. My code a following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Person{
public:
    std::string name = "jack";
};

std::vector<Person> test() {
    std::vector<Person> vec;
    Person p1, p2, p3;
    vec.push_back(p1);
    vec.push_back(p2);
    vec.push_back(p3);
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    //why I didn't get an empty vector object? because it's not a pointer.
    std::vector<Person> vec = test();
    std::cout << vec.at(0).name << "\n";
    std::cout << vec.at(1).name << "\n";
}
```

Comment: A copy of the vector is returned.

Comment: @RetiredNinja A copy of the vector would be returned. Though mandatory copy-elision means there is exactly one vector in that program.

Comment: @Deduplicator True, but I figured if someone wanted to explain the details they'd write an answer. I'm also a bit fuzzy on if that requires a certain C++ version or if NRVO could be involved, etc. So, conceptually copy is a simple explanation.

Comment: Before C++17, the semantics (meaning) of your code is that a copy of vector is returned to the caller, and the implementation is permitted but not required to elide the copy (which practically means that some compilers, with some optimisation settings do perform NRVO but some don't).    From C++17, the implementation is required to elide the copy

Comment: @Peter Is that correct? I thought only RVO was mandatory, not NRVO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result object of the function call is copy-initialized from `vec`, before `vec` (and other local objects) gets destroyed.

For [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes):

> The copy-initialization of the result of the function call is sequenced-before the destruction of all temporaries at the end of expression, which, in turn, is sequenced-before the destruction of local variables of the block enclosing the return statement.

Comment: if the method returned a char[], why is it not ok?

Comment: does that mean c++ will copy all of object were returned, but not for arrays? or, do you suggest me always return a vector pointer instead of vector?

Comment: @Jack Array decays to pointers, that means the function returns pointer but not the whole array; and pointer but not the array is copied.

Comment: @Jack a function can't return a `type[]` array. But it can return a `std::array<type,N>` instead.